# Maven - how/where to publish artifacts

Tags: maven-2, repository, nexus

I have open-sourced some of my projects.  I'd like to publish the artifacts in a common place.  If I don't have to host my own repository, that would be ideal, otherwise I will have to setup my own instance of Nexus (or other repository that you recommend).

Can I publish artifacts to Maven Central?  What process do I need to follow to get them there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can, especially if it is an open source project. Here is some info:

http://central.sonatype.org/pages/ossrh-guide.html

Comment: This is what I have deployed so far:
https://oss.sonatype.org/index.html#nexus-search;quick~walterjwhite