# How does maven find the artifacts?

Tags: maven-2, repository, conventions

I'm trying to use as library a poorly documented piece of software. On the website they listed the *Artifact IDs* of its dependencies, but then I guess they removed one of the pieces.

The `mvn compile` command (on my project, using the other as dependency) I get the following error for one of the dependencies:

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building <my software> 0.1
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[WARNING] The POM for <my dependency> no dependency information available
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 0.426s
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project <my project>: Could not resolve dependencies for project <my project>: Failure to find <my dependency> in http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced -> [Help 1]
```

Searching on the Internet I found out that Maven uses, by default, a world-wise centralized repository on *ibiblio.org*, but it's **very** unlikely that they're using it.

As they are not supporting me, I need to find my way through their stuff, so my question is: is there a standard way of publishing maven repositories?

For instance, is there a lookup system associated to the *groupId* (which is usually in the form `org.example.something`)?

---

**Related question:** [Maven - how/where to publish artifacts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3266519/maven-how-where-to-publish-artifacts?rq=1)

Comment: In addition to @khmarbaise's excellent answer, I can recommend the **Maven Repository** section in [this tutorial site](http://www.mkyong.com/tutorials/maven-tutorials/).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The default place where maven is getting it's artifacts from is [Maven Central](http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2) whereas *ibiblio.org* is only a mirror of Maven Central ([see repository guide](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/MAVENUSER/Mirrors+Repositories)). See the [repository guide](http://maven.apache.org/repository/index.html).

Furthermore there is no relationship between the groupId and a maven [repository](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-repositories.html). The best is to [search for artifacts in Maven central](http://search.maven.org/).

Apart from that you should delete the part of your local repository (.m2/repository/) where the requested artifact is located cause based on the message you got it looks you tried to get an artifact which does not have the given groupId/artifactId/version coordinates.

The best way to solve such kind of problems is to install a [repository manager](http://maven.apache.org/repository-management.html) and install the required artifacts into the repository manager.

On the other hand to [upload artifacts to maven central](http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-central-repository-upload.html) is not really a problem.